# trigger io chrome extension does not seem to work

Tags: google-chrome-extension, trigger.io

I am trying trigger io for the first time.

I am trying to use the chrome extension and eventually would like to get to a point where I can run/debug (using chrome developer tools) on the browser before deploying to IOS and android.

I created the default app you have - I am able to run it on IOS simulator.

When I run it on chrome, I get the following:
The required steps are:

```
1) Go to chrome:extensions in the Chrome browser
2) Make sure "developer mode" is on (top right corner)')
3) Use "Load unpacked extension" and select the folder:
```

I have followed the instructions given but even if I quit the browser and relaunch it and run the forge build for the default app, I get the same response.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does the extension install when you run through those steps?

Comment: yes. however, i can not get it to build on chrome. I can get it to run on ios simulator and can use forge logging (awesome feature, btw) but would love to have it working on chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the extension install when you run through the steps you list in your question?

Note, to see your app running in Chrome, you'll need to use something like the [button module](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/button.html)...

**However**, if you just want to see your app running in a browser so you can use developer tools, click "web" instead of "chrome" - it will open as a web app in your browser.

Comment: Yes it does. I see the button installed. Given mine is a single page app, it should be possible to run it locally on chrome?

Comment: OK, and when you click on the button the app's not displayed? If you just want to use the Chrome developer tools, see my comment about using the web target. Debugging Chrome extensions is more awkward than debugging web apps!

Comment: Thanks James, I would try the web route.